# How to accessing the value in fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener, fieldset

I am writing a code that will allow users to write note, I'm using **fieldset** instead of textarea. I need to access the value in the **fieldset** and make use of the text. I can't access it unless I add an input elements.

```
const write = document.querySelector("#write");
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const form = document.querySelector("#form")
const list = document.querySelector("#list");
const button = document.createElement("button");

write.addEventListener("click", function (e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e);
        const page = document.createElement("form");
        const fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset");
        page.action = "./nowhere";
        fieldset.contentEditable = true;
        fieldset.id = "text";
        fieldset.name = "text";
        // fieldset.append(input)
        page.append(fieldset);
        write.append(page);
        page.append(button);
        const myText = write.form.fieldset.value;
        console.log(myText);
})
```

Comment: Start by writing semantic HTML. A fieldset is designed to group a set of fields (inputs/selects/etc), not be a freeform form control of its own right. If don't know why you are avoiding textarea but if you are going to replace it with a contentEditable element then you probably want a div instead.

Comment: There is no `name` attribute for fieldsets.

Comment: " I can't access it" - what does this mean? How do you try to access it? What result do you expect?